# Get rid of all empty strings values in jsonb | Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have rather abstract question on `PostgreSQL` `jsonb` data.

For example I have a table called… `table_one`, where I have  a column:

```
my_jsonb_column   jsonb;
```

In 100% cases in contains flat `json` structure like

example:

```
{"one": null, "two": 0, "three": "" }
```

might be different length or `null` but always flat.

My goal is like that.

Whenever I select this column I need to somehow convert empty string values `“”` into `null` for each member of json where it’s value is `“”`

example :

```
{"one": null, "two": 0, "three": "" }  - > {"one": null, "two": 0, "three": null }
```

Preferable without PLPGsQL

Postgres version - 11

Thank you.

Comment: maybe too simplistic to just search for `""` and replace with *null*? --> `WITH j (val) AS ( VALUES ('{"one": null, "two": 0, "three": "" }'::jsonb)) SELECT replace(val::text,'""','null')::jsonb FROM j`

Comment: Nice and clean, but unfortunately "" is a valid JSON key and *null* is not :)

Comment: @Stefanov.sm you're right.. I was just considering values, not keys... thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @JimJones and "this\"" will bang too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid writing a function, try searching for the empty string `""` and using `replace` to change it to `null`

```
WITH j (val) AS (
  VALUES ('{"one": null, "two": 0, "three": "" }'::jsonb)
) SELECT replace(val::text,'""','null')::jsonb FROM j;

                replace                 
----------------------------------------
 {"one": null, "two": 0, "three": null}
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=78f9a1218bdbeea223a19f3e284c7a03)

If you want the empty strings to be replaced even if you don't say so in your `SELECT`, you might want to write a [`TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtrigger.html) on `INSERT` or `UPDATE` to keep the jsonb column clean for future selects. Depending on your use case it might be also interesting to take a look at [`GENERATATED COLUMNS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-generated-columns.html).

**Note**: as pointed out by @Stefanov.sm, a simple replace wouldn't work if there are keys with empty strings.

Comment: To avoid certain cases (empty string keys, values like "this\"") better use `regexp_replace(val::text, '[^\\]("")[^:]?', 'null')` instead of `replace(val::text,'""','null')`. The regexp can be further improved.

Answer (score 1):

As a plpgsql function:

```sql
create function jsonb_es_to_null(arg_j jsonb) returns jsonb immutable strict as
$body$
 declare retval jsonb := '{}'::jsonb;
 r record;
 begin
    for r in select * from jsonb_each(arg_j) loop
        retval := retval || jsonb_build_object(r.key, case when r.value <> '""' then r.value end);
    end loop;
    return retval;
 end;
$body$ language plpgsql;
```